# My home router has been hacked, what can I do?

Tags: network, wifi, spyware

My router has been hacked and all devices have had some sort of spyware installed (Don't ask me how I know this, just please take my word for it).

Since they can see everything I do on my devices, they can also see what I change my router password to every time. When I disconnect from wifi and use data they still have access to my device. I even did a factory reset, inserted a new sim and then set it up using data, but they still somehow had access. What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

Easy: disconnect the router from the internet and turn off data on your mobile. You still have a home network, but no access to the internet and the attacker is cut off.

Connect to the router from wifi and reset the router to factory settings (see your manual).

Factory reset your mobile devices.

Everything is now back to a safe state.

Comment: I've reset the router a million times, I've also factory reset my devices and switched to using data only, both failed to work, I plan on changing internet suppliers,will that help?

Comment: No it will not. If you have done those things, then you are not hacked. And your desire to not give evidence as to why you think you are suggests that you already knew we would say that. "Doctor, I have cancer. Don't bother checking if I do, but how can I perform surgery on myself to cure the cancer?" The answer above is the answer to what you have asked. If you want more, you need to get into the details.

Comment: On my iphone they(the hackers) are sending me push notifications, after I had reset my phone, i switched sims, made a new icloud and when i connected to 4G, I was still receiving them. I then got a new phone, new sim and only used data and that device is not affected. It is worth nothing I know who these people are.

Comment: also  If I reset the router, but not my devices they will still have access to my devices however will they be able to still infect other devices that I do not currently have connected to the network?

Comment: Your iPhone push notifications are not evidence of being "hacked". More details required on that one.

Comment: Theoretically, if the attacker has full control over a device (we have not established that is the case), then the device could be used to launch attacks to other devices on the network. If those devices have vulnerabilities, they might get "infected". Note all the conditionals in that sentence. If a device is not connected to the network, there is no way for a malicious device to contact it.

Comment: The push notifications are messages that only I can relate too, I am basically being cyber bullied/teased. They are personal messages. Also I should also add when I reset the router, it was connected to the internet. But that still doesn't explain how after factory resetting my phone, it was still being hacked. Another instance of I know I'm hacked is once I was on my phone, they took a screenshot.  I'm guessing they are using some sort of software like team viewer.

Comment: That just means someone knows how to text/message/use an app you use to send messages. It does not indicate that anyone has access to your device.

Comment: might I also add, they have access to my microphone on my devices

Comment: I will give you a few examples, when I talk about something in the house with someone, they start sending me push notifications on something related to what I was talking about, or sometimes, I am in the kitchen and I go on instagram, my entire feed is full of picutres of kitchens(I have no idea how this is even possible), they are teasing me at all times. How else do they know where I am or what I'm talking about if they do not have access to my camera and microphone

Comment: Instagram: no attacker can accomplish that; there is another explanation. You use the term "push notifications" but that's a generic term. What *app* is displaying the notifications?

Comment: it was a sky news notification, the one they send for breaking news

Comment: Uh, so give me an example. You are talking about X, and then a Sky News alert shows up about Y. Can you give me what X and Y are?

Comment: So I'm talking about X, and then a Sky news alert shows up but it has a custom message, with something I was discussing or other times something personal.

Comment: Check the permissions on the Sky news app for me. Does it have permissions to access your microphone?

Comment: No, permissions has been turned off and I would still receive notifications

Comment: @zZurf  There's many people that think various apps are "listening to them" because they then get some clue later on about what they were talking about.  There actually have been people who've looked into this, using various technical means, and found no evidence it's happening.  Basically the algorithms have just gotten good at using the data you provide them through searches, Facebook, etc to just get good at predicting what you're interested in.  https://finance.yahoo.com/news/facebook-amazon-google-smartphone-spying-170721118.html

Comment: @zZurf The short story is, that there's no need to listen in on your conversations.  The tech companies already know so much about you, and how everyone else behaves that they can just target you fairly easily.  Masses of people all behave similarly, and when you have data on masses of people, you can fairly easily predict behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101573/discussion-between-j-a-k-and-zzurf).

Answer (score 2):

I have some doubts, like schroeder that your home router was hacked.  The more likely explanation is something else in your network is infected.

If you want to be 99% sure, flash the router firmware to the latest/greatest, and factory reset it.

If you want to be 100% sure, buy a new router from a completely different manufacturer and completely disconnect the old one.

Solving problems is about isolation, and questioning (and confirming through experiment) your assumptions.  If you don't do both of these it's highly likely you're going down the wrong path.

Comment: It's 100% a hack because I know who is doing this and that person got a hold of my router password and all this has been happening ever since.

Comment: Even with all the details you provided, I'm not convinced this is a hack at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset the router to factory defaults and the install the latest official firmware available for it. Do that on a different system that is not infected.
2. Format and reinstall all your affected systems. Do not connect them again to the network until they are all clean.

Comment: what if I connected them to the network while not clean? Can they affect other devices or the network? Also I have alot of devices, how can I check which one is affected and which one isn't?

Comment: Yes, they can. An infected system may attempt to re-spread the infection or re-gain control of the router.

Comment: But the only way they managed to infect my devices in the first place was because they gained entry through my router. That has now been changed as I followed schroders advice above and changed all the password of the router by disconnected the internet connection. My router was not really hacked into but it was just that they found out the master password and gained access. So that's why I do not think they'll be able to get access to my network anymore. However my devices still have some kind of spyware installed.

Comment: That's why you need to format all devices or at least try to deep-clean them.

Comment: What does format mean?

Comment: Completely erase all drives and reinstall.